# Path saving files with textlogs

Tags: vb.net

I want to save my logtext files in my C:\ or anywhere, what code should i use instead of application.startuppath. can you guys help me out? Thanks a lot! :>

```
Dim filename As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & TextBox1.Text & " TimeinTimeout.log"
Dim sw As StreamWriter = AppendText(filename)
sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text & " has " & " Timed In " & Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt dd-MM-yy"))
sw.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Application.StartupPath` and just put whatever path you want. For example, to write to the `C:\Temp` folder:

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\Temp\" & TextBox1.Text & " TimeinTimeout.log"
```

Also, your code to write to the file will not work. You want to do something like this:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(filename, True)
    sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text & " has " & " Timed In " & Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt dd-MM-yy"))
End Using
```

The `True` parameter to the `StreamWriter` constructor specifies to *append* to `filename`. Also, `StreamWriter` implements the `IDisposable` interface, and so it must be disposed of, hence the `Using` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Application.StartupPath enter a string that has the path where you want to save the file....example: " \test\appl\EDI\Jobs\Prod\Outbox\PriceLists"